# Examples of abstractions that did *not* turn out to be useful

Tags: ho.history-overview, mathematical-philosophy

I’ve read (but cannot find any reference now) that new abstract mathematical concepts like set theory and – not too long ago – category theory were in their time often considered too abstract to be useful.

But now, all of them have turned out to be useful. What are examples of abstractions that were once somewhat popular, but have in fact *not* turned out be useful (or even turned out to be *not* useful)?

Comment: Maybe one should make this a cw with people proposing candidates of useless theories and others adding in comments if they know of some use for one of the purportedly useless concepts.

Comment: What does this exactly mean that a math theory is "not useful"? What is the criterion? Theories come and go out of fashion, and there are many examples of theories which were not developed for decades, and then came back to fashion.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko For the sake of giving a definition (and only for it), we say that a new theory *has been useful* if it has been used to solve an existing problem that has been posed before the new theory and that recordedly has withstood at least one previous attempt not using the new theory. Please don’t ask me again to do something like this.

Comment: k.stm, regarding "Please don’t ask me again to do something like this." To do something like what?  If a user finds a question problematic and requests clarification in good faith, then I don't see the grounds for complaint.

Comment: @ToddTrimble No, that’s true, wasn’t meant as a complaint. The word “exactly” made me feel like I need to give a definition, and I just hate to give definitions of non-mathematical terms. Sorry if that came out rude.

Comment: k.stm, thanks for clarifying; I understand now.

Comment: @k.stm: I ignore your last sentence, but I still would like to better understand your definition: can you give one example of "not useful" theory in math, abstract or not?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko No, sorry – I don’t think I can. I firmly believe that all theories I have been taught, have studied or heard of so far, have really been useful in the sense above. After all, such examples are what I am asking for! I know I sometimes try to generalize stuff (like trying to find the most general structure where I can make sense of differentiability or constructing some sort of category for dynamical systems) which of course never is useful. I probably imagine something like that, on a way more sophisticated level. Does this help?

Comment: One way a theory could turn out to be useless is if it involves questionable axioms that turn out to be inconsistent (although one could argue that naive set theory is inconsistent but useful) such as has happened with some large cardinal axioms. (J. D. Hamkins: "[Perlmutter] ended up refuting the existence of what are now called the excessively hypercompact cardinals, which had appeared in several published articles. " http://jdh.hamkins.org/tag/hypercompact/) Another way a theory could be useless is if it is superceded by some result, say that it is a complicated way to calculate 0.

Comment: I vote to close. This question has way too much potential to offend. Moreover, if something is not a useful thing to know, then I don't care about it.

Answer (score 5):

I don't have an opinion of my own about Fuzzy Set Theory, but someone whom I respect, Saunders Mac Lane, seemed to think it wasn't a very fruitful development. (I freely acknowledge he could be opinionated at times, and he may have had his blind spots.) He mentions this example in his book *Mathematics: Form and Function*.

I invite others to explain to me what solutions to problems (or insightful points of view on problems) Fuzzy Set Theory has enabled, in the spirit of the proposed working definition of useful theory: something used to solve an existing problem that was posed before the theory was invented and that recordedly has withstood at least one previous attempt not using the new theory. Of course, fuzzy set theory may itself be a 'fuzzy' or at least broad term, in that it is cousin to other forms of set theory which do have their purpose, such as Heyting- or Boolean-valued set theory.

Comment: I know that some washing machines use “fuzzy logic” at least.